# Different blessing when lighting candles on Rosh Hashanah

Tags: halacha, chabad, chagim-holidays

On every holiday the blessing for candle lighting is "lehadlik ner shel Yom Tov".

Why, according to Chabad custom, specifically on Rosh Hashanah there is a distinction made and the blessing is "lehadlik ner shel Yom Hazikaron"?

Comment: Some Jews recite no blessing when lighting candles for Yom Tov. You can light candles whenever on Yom Tov so there's no need for a special command to light some.

Comment: The question could be generalized. Why is the end of the middle bracha of Shemoneh Esrei and of the second bracha of Kiddush מקדש ישראל והזמנים for all other Yomim Tovim, and מקדש ישראל ויום הזכרון on Rosh Hashanah? Whatever the reason is for the latter, it would probably explain the OP's question as well.

Comment: @Meir - Shemoneh Esrei would need to be similar t the bracha - מעין החתימה, that would nor apply to candle lighting. Moadim U'Zmanim [7/233 in footnote] asks this question on the Chabad minhag, and does not give an answer.

Comment: @פריזהב Thanks for that. I'm not sure I understand what R. Shternbuch is saying, though. How is יום הזכרון a מעין of מלוך על כל העולם? I can understand מלך על כל הארץ, but not the rest.

Comment: @Meir That would make sense if the blessing for the other days was נר של זמנים

Comment: http://shulchanharav.com/contents.asp?aid=118142#_ftn100